# Finding the function with power series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{4n}}{(2n)!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

I need to find what function is equal to the series
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{4n}}{(2n)!} $$

I found the power series of $e^{x^2}$ and $e^{-x^2}$ but when I'm adding them together I don't understand why $n!$ should be changed to $2n!$, what the best technique for this type of questions?

$$e^{x^2} = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$$

$$e^{-x^2} =\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n}}{n!}$$

Comment: Start with $\cosh x$.

Comment: I can use only the power series of $e^x$, $ln(1+x)$,$sin(x)$,$cos(x)$ $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: $\cosh x=(e^x+e^{-x})/2$. It's the even part of $e^x$, hence only the even terms of the series.

Comment: this doesn't help me cause I cant use it, is there a way to do it by summing the 2 series I wrote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track. If you sum the two series then you get
$$
e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2}= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n}}{n!}
= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \bigl(1 + (-1)^n \bigr) \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} \, .
$$
Now note that $1 + (-1)^n$ is zero for odd $n$ and equal to $2$ for even $n$, so that
$$
e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2} = 2 \sum_{\substack{n=0 \\ \text{$n$ even}}}^{\infty }
\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}  \, .
$$
Then substitute $n=2m$ in order to sum over all even indices:
$$
2 \sum_{\substack{n=0 \\ \text{$n$ even}}}^{\infty }
\frac{x^{2n}}{n!} =  2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4m}}{(2m)!} \, .
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4m}}{(2m)!} = \frac 12 (e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2}) = \cosh(x^2)
$$